Replace some values in one dataset with values in another dataset [SAS]
I have a dataset (data1) where there are some missing values. I have the imputed values stored in another dataset (samples2), where the variable VAL_x represents the row number x in data1. What I want to do is loop through each row in samples2 (each row represents a simulation), in each loop, check each observation if flag=1, if true, extract the row number of that observation, say x, and replace aval with VAL_x in samples2. I also attached my code sample, I don't know why it doesn't work. Please help, thank you!!
data data1;
  input id $8. trt $2. aval flag;
  datalines;
  000001 1 0.12345 0
  000042 2 0.23456 0
  000093 1 0.34567 0
  000074 2 0.45678 1
  000905 1 0.56789 1
  000016 2 0.67890 0
  000007 1 0.78901 1
  000408 2 0.89012 1
  000059 1 0.90123 0
  000210 2 0.01234 0
  ;
run;

data samples2;
  input VAL_4 VAL_5 VAL_7 VAL_8 random1 random2;
  datalines;
1.23 4.56 7.89 0.12 3.45 6.78
2.34 5.67 8.90 1.23 4.56 7.89
3.45 6.78 9.01 2.34 5.67 8.90
4.56 7.89 0.12 3.45 6.78 9.01
5.67 8.90 1.23 4.56 7.89 0.12
;
run;

data data2;
    length varname $10;
    do i=1 to 5; /*nrow in samples2*/
        set data1;
        if flag=1 then do;
            row_number = _N_; 
            varname=cat('VAL_', row_number);
            set samples2 point=i;
            aval=input(vvalue(varname), best.); /*Here is where I got error*/
        end;
        sim=i;
        output;
    end;
    drop i varname;
run;


I am confused by samples2. Excluding random1 and random2, it is a 5x4 matrix, but you have 10 rows of data1. VAL_4-VAL_8 corrspond to individual rows. Suppose I'm on row 4 of data1. I need to pull a value from VAL_4. Which value do I pull of the five?

hi, plz  read FAQ How to ask and try to phrase your question better.
an example of the expected result would make it easier to understand... thx


where the variable AVAL_x

There's no such variable in your example

What I want to do is loop through each row in samples2, check each observation if flag=1,

There's no FLAG variable in SAMPLES2
Also, please supply the expected result.

VAL_x is in samples2 dataset, where x represents the row number in data1 with missing values. flag variable is in data1, aval=. when flag=1.
